# MySQL sum multiple duplicated rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables
In first table, "items", stored items with prices:

```
id  price
1   40
2   55
3   70
```

In second table, "sets", stored sets of items, and items, contained in set, stored as comma separated list:

```
id  items
1   1,2,3
2   2,2,3,3
3   1,2,1,2
```

I need to get total price of sets.

```
SELECT id, (
    SELECT SUM(price)
    FROM `items` AS i
    WHERE i.id IN ( s.items )
) AS total_price
FROM `sets` AS s
```

But if in "s.items" exists duplicates, sum is wrong.

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: You should fix your data format so you have a proper junction table (a row for each item and id).  Storing numeric ids in string lists is a very bad data structure.  Plus, your query is incorrect anyway.

Comment: Gordon is right. I urge you not to accept any answers and first fix the way your database is constructed. What you have here is a many-to-many relationship and it is solved using a join/junction table. Go read up on many-to-many relationships as you will find them relatively common and constructing your database in a proper manner will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: I would like to restructure database, but I can't. I need to get total sum on current structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem by myself.
I wrote function in SQL. Called it "calcSum", and it have one TEXT parameter "list":

```
BEGIN
DECLARE strLen INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE subStrLen INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE totalSum INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;

IF list IS NULL THEN
    SET list = '';
END IF;

traversing:
LOOP
    SET strLen = CHAR_LENGTH( list );
    SELECT price INTO x FROM items WHERE id =  SUBSTRING_INDEX( list, ',', 1 );
    SET totalSum = totalSum + x;
    SET subStrLen = CHAR_LENGTH( SUBSTRING_INDEX( list, ',', 1 ) ) + 2;
    SET list = MID( list, subStrLen, strLen );
    IF list = '' THEN
        LEAVE traversing;
    END IF;
END LOOP traversing;

RETURN totalSum;
END
```

And rewrote query with new function

```
SELECT id, calcSum(s.items) AS total_price
FROM `sets` AS s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"item"
item_id  price
1        40
2        55
3        70

"sets"
set_id  set_name
1       blah
2       wow
3       awesome

"set_item"
set_item_id   set_id   item_id
1             1        1
2             1        2
3             1        3
4             2        2
5             2        2
6             2        3
7             2        3
8             3        1
9             3        2
10            3        1
11            3        2

select s.set_id,s.set_name, sum(i.price)
from set_item si
join sets s on si.set_id = s.set_id
join item i on si.item_id = i.item_id
group by si.set_id;

+--------+----------+--------------+
| set_id | set_name | sum(i.price) |
+--------+----------+--------------+
|      1 | blah     |          165 |
|      2 | wow      |          250 |
|      3 | awesome  |          190 |
+--------+----------+--------------+
```